How to make a regular expression and return to a data frame?
I have a table with Naics, but I want just the number and to return this number to the data frame, example:
In  'Biomass Electric Power Generation(221117)'
I want (221117)
How I doing:
tabel_sector<-sector$`Main Activities (NAICS)`
tabel_sector|> separate(sector$`Main Activities (NAICS)`,c("key", "value"), "( )")|>str()    
tabel_sector|> separate(sector$`Main Activities (NAICS)`, c("key", "value"), "( )", convert=TRUE)|> str()

